# How to search whether a value is present in a list of values in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

In my model a list of values is stored. Now a user can enter a list of values and if any of the values is present in the table then that record should be fetched.

For e.g. a user enters [3, 63, 2, 5]. Now suppose the list that is present in the table has values [65, 5, 8, 48]. Since the input list which is [3, 63, 2, 5] has got a common value which is 5 in this case I should get this record.

This is the column which is present in my model. The model name is Room.

```
room_number = models.CharField(validators=[validate_comma_separated_integer_list], max_length=4000)
```

I don't understand how I can do this. Can someone please help me with this?

I can get an individual value and run a for loop for every value present in the input list. but I don't understand how I can search whether a given value is present in the list.

Comment: Why are you using a CharField, especially if you want to filter it numerically? Why not an integerfield or decimalfield? and best suit for you will be  ArrayField if your database is postgres

Comment: read more here `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/`

Comment: @lordstock I am using the default database which is SQLite. integerfield or decimalfield cannot store a list of numbers at least in SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

change room_number field in model to

```
room_number = models.TextField()
```

try to implement your validate_comma_separated_integer_list logic before saving list to model
and while saving simply do

```
room_numbers = json.dumps(room_numbers)
```

and save this json string to database and while fetching loads it to normal list using

```
input_list = [3, 63, 2, 5]
room_numbers = json.loads(room.room_numbers)
common_rooms = list(set(input_list).intersection(set(room_numbers))) # common rooms
```